# Why I am getting SIGBART error in this code of diagonal traversal of Binary tree?

Tags: c++14, binary-tree

I am getting SIGBART error in this code. I am trying to print diagonal traversal of a binary tree.

```
void digonalUtil(Node* root,int dVal,map<int,vector<int> > &mp){
    if(root==NULL) return;
    
    mp[dVal].push_back(root->data);
    
    digonalUtil(root->left,dVal+1,mp);
    digonalUtil(root->right,dVal,mp);
}

vector<int> diagonal(Node *root)
{
   // your code here
   vector<int> ans;
   if(root==NULL) return ans;
   
   map<int,vector<int> > mp;
   digonalUtil(root,0,mp);
   
   for(auto itr=mp.begin();itr!=mp.end();itr++){
       for(auto ptr=itr->second.begin();ptr!=itr->second.end();itr++){
           ans.push_back(*ptr);
       }
   }
   return ans;
   
}
```

While a bit commenting out statements, I find that the error is in the line

```
mp[dVal].push_back(root->data);
```

But I am not getting why is this happening. I had earlier done same operation on map in other questions, there it worked fine.

Please help.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code shown. To the extent there is a problem, it likely lies in the code not shown; perhaps in how the tree is built in the first place. For further assistance, prepare a [mcve].

Comment: I found the problem today, in the second for loop I am incrementing itr, which should be ptr++, this was causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, in the second for loop I was incrementing itr rather than ptr that was causing the error, it was just a silly mistake I can say.